# write lambda function for deregister ami and corresponding snapshot should be deleted

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have created following lambda function on my local machine so I can deploy it and run it through cloudwatch event cron expression on daily basis to cleanup the desired AMI and its SnapShots. It also takes care of abandon EBS SnapShots as well.

The criteria of deleting the AMI is first find the AMI that have **ASGfrontendWP_AMI_** tag, and if its more than 1 day old, mark it for **deregister**. The function exempt the AMI which is currently being used by AWS Launch Configuration.

I am sure there are few ways to optimize this lambda function and code and I would like to know how can I delete corresponding **snapshot** on the basis of **ami-id**. Here is my code

```
import boto3
from dateutil.parser import parse

import datetime
client = boto3.client('ec2')
current_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()

age = 1
def handler(event, context):

    def days_old(date):
        get_date_obj = parse(date)
        date_obj = get_date_obj.replace(tzinfo=None)
        diff = datetime.datetime.now() - date_obj
        return diff.days
    
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
    amis = ec2.describe_images(Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'name',
                'Values': ['ASGfrontendWP_AMI_'+'*']
            }
    ])
    #filter ami-id and snapshot-id  
    for ami in amis['Images']:
        create_date = ami['CreationDate']
        ami_id = ami['ImageId']
        # print ami['ImageId'], ami['CreationDate']
        day_old = days_old(create_date)
        if day_old >= age:
            print ("deleting -> " + ami_id + " - create_date = " + create_date)
            # deregister the AMI
            ec2.deregister_image(ImageId=ami_id)
        for snap in ami['BlockDeviceMappings']:
            #store snapshots
            s_id = snap['Ebs']['SnapshotId']
    
    return amis    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
    }

#handler("test", "test")
```

Comment: Are just missing this piece? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.delete_snapshot

Comment: yes, Please add some code in it.